# Playing around with monkey patching Rails ActionController to implement dependency injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I've been learning Rails recently, and coming from .NET/C# development, one thing that immediately struck me is that Rails controllers don't have constructors, and thus you can't implement constructor dependency injection - at least not as it is envisioned in other languages. I understand that there are other best practices in Rails/ways around this, but I thought it would be a fun and educational little project to see if I could implement a .NET like DI framework in Rails. In reading up on Rails internals, I found that the controller is actually instantiated in the [ActionController class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L250). I figured I could monkey patch this class, and use my own DI framework to create the controllers. It turns out that it is essentially possible to do this, and I have it mostly working, except that when I use my custom DI injection instead of the call to `new.dispatch(name, req, res)` it appears that styling is not being loaded on the page, so clearly I am missing something important here.

Here is my custom `Injector` class:

```
require "singleton"

class Injector
    include Singleton
  
    def self.register(class_name, *params)
      @services[class_name] = *params
    end
  
    def self.get_service(class_name)
      klass = Object.const_get(class_name)
      params = @services[class_name]
      if (params.length == 0)
        return klass.new()
      else
        klass.new(*@services[class_name])
      end
    end
    
    private
  
    @services = {}
end
```

which is use like this, in the application.rb file to register dependencies:

```
CONFIG = YAML.load_file("config/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]

Injector.register("UsersRepository")
Injector.register("SecretsAdapter", CONFIG["secret_location"])
Injector.register("AuthService", Injector.get_service("SecretsAdapter"))
Injector.register("UsersController", Injector.get_service("UsersRepository"), Injector.get_service("AuthService"))
```

and then here is my monkey-patched ActionController where `Injector` is used to resolve dependencies:

```
require_relative '../../lib/injection/injector'

module ActionController
    class Metal < AbstractController::Base
        def self.dispatch(name, req, res)
            if middleware_stack.any?
                #not implemented with Injector yet
                middleware_stack.build(name) { |env| new.dispatch(name, req, res) }.call req.env
            else
                controller = Injector.get_service(self.to_s)
                controller.dispatch(name, req, res)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

These 2 lines are the key:

```
controller = Injector.get_service(self.to_s)
controller.dispatch(name, req, res)
```

and this is working in that it calls the initialize method on the controller, with the correct parameters and the page loads. However, when I use my monkey-patched code, CSS styling does not appear to be loading. When I use the `new.dispatch` call (not monkey-patched) everything is good. So my question is, why is styling not being loaded with the monkey-patched code? And yes, I understand that this is likely not a best practice. It is really just so I can learn some of the Rails internals and play around with it a bit.

Comment: Where are you putting your CSS? In `app/controllers/stylesheets/<model_name>s` like the default? See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets

Comment: yes they are in the default `app/assets/stylesheets/<model_name>s`

Comment: You might be interested in https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-system/0.17/ and https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-auto_inject/0.6/ if you haven't already seen those gems.

Comment: These are both interesting gems, but it doesn't answer my question. Nor do these gems seem to allow controller dependency injection in a Rails app.

Comment: I think you need do a call to `super` in some way. I'd try tracing the path of `dispatch` in a normal controller by looking over the code in Github, and I bet something will be clear.

IMHO, generally in Rails (and Ruby in general), patterns from other languages don't really translate *because* they end up not really being necessary. Like, it's a PITA to do curried functions in Ruby.... but you also never need to, b/c of blocks & yield.